# Injecting HTML into the DOM destroys the AngularJS events

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have included a third party script in my angularJS app, which appends some HTML to the body

```
document.body.innerHTML += thirdPartyHTML;
```

Whenever that is done it seems like my `ng-click` events won't fire. Is the HTML by the third party script appending the HTML in the wrong way, or should I somehow refresh AngularJS view on the DOM `($scope.$apply)`?

**Update**: It seems like I can reproduce the error, with just calling document.body.innerHTML += ''; myself. It apparently hasn't anything to do with the onclick event. If you have your own AngularJS app, you can try to call document.body.innerHTML += ''; after the document has loaded, and none of the ng-click events work.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't also adding event handlers to the body in an unsafe way that might unhook the existing ones? What does the third party code do?

Comment: It just add one event to their own button like this: document.getElementById('my_button').onclick = function(){...}. It just seems to destroy my ng-click on my own DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever `innerHTML` is changed the browser has to recreate the DOM tree. That means that all information associated with the existing DOM elements is lost.

This does not only include event listeners. Angular stores scopes and controllers on DOM elements. So basically the application is gone.

If the third party app really changes the `innerHTML`of the body element, then you better let it run before angular.

As an alternative you can initialize the application manually and don't use the `ng-app`. The details can be found in [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50889/discussion-between-dofs-and-zeroflagl)