# AngularJS DOM modification deletes events -> need viable workaround implementation schema

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, d3.js, event-handling

Could someone explain to me the right way to create custom event listeners in AngularJS that resist DOM modifications?

My problem is that I need to plot 2 different datasets according to a dropdown menu. Each element of the datasets has to respond to an event (mouseover/mousemove etc...). But when switching from one dataset to another, the event listener is lost.
This behavior is well explained here:

- [Injecting HTML into the DOM destroys the AngularJS events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119434/injecting-html-into-the-dom-destroys-the-angularjs-events)

but I do not understand the answer given to bypass it. The post mentions that manually avoiding ng-app can help but it seems like a bad workaround.

I would rather redefine my own event listeners such that they would not be lost during DOM modification. Can someone tell me how to correctly use `addEventListener` in the directive/controller model?

Here is an SSCCE html/javascript file that illustrates how my program is organized

```js
angular.module("testUpdate", [])

.directive("shape", function($parse) {

  return {

    restrict: "E",
    replace: false,
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      
      // draw dataset according to #shapeSelection choice

      d3.select("#shapeSelection")
        .on("change", scope.redraw);
      
      // change color on mouseover

      d3.selectAll("circle,rect,polygon")
        .on("mouseover", function() {
          d3.select(this).style("fill", "#0f0");
        });

    }
  };
})


.controller("testController", function($scope) {

  $scope.shape = "none";
  
  //create datasets
  
  $scope.dataset1 = [{
    cx: 10,
    cy: 20
  }, {
    cx: 30,
    cy: 20
  }];
  $scope.dataset2 = [{
    w: 20,
    h: 20
  }];


  // the triangle actually responds to the event
  
  d3.selectAll("svg")
    .append("polygon")
    .attr("points", "15,20 0,40 30,40")
    .style("fill", "#f00");
  
  // draw dataset depending on the user choice

  $scope.draw = function() {

    if ($scope.shape === "circle") {
      d3.selectAll("svg").selectAll("circle")
        .data($scope.dataset1).enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.cx; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.cy; })
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", "#f00");
    } 
    
    else if ($scope.shape === "rect") {
      d3.selectAll("svg").selectAll("rect")
        .data($scope.dataset2).enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", function(d) { return d.w; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return d.h; })
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .style("fill", "#f00");
    } 
    
    else {}
  }
  
  // once removed is called, the event listener is destroyed

  $scope.redraw = function() {
    d3.selectAll("circle,rect,polygon").remove();
    $scope.draw()
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>



<div ng-app="testUpdate" ng-controller="testController">
  <select name="shapeSelector" ng-model="shape" id="shapeSelection">
    <option value="none">--none--</option>
    <option value="circle">dataset1</option>
    <option value="rect">dataset2</option>
  </select>
  <shape id="shapeTag">
    <svg id="shapeSVG" display="block"></svg>
  </shape>
</div>
```

The `d3.selection.remove()` function modifies the DOM and nullifies the event listeners so that the triangle responds correctly but not the circles and rectangle.

A dirty workaround would be to create the DOM for both datasets and set the visibility of the non-selected one to hidden, but both datasets are pretty big so it is not a viable option.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code, it appears that you only want to have the `mouseover` event captured on the elements inside the `shape` directive.

I think the best solution for you would be to move the code which binds the event handler to the elements into `$scope.redraw` or the `$scope.draw` function:

```
  $scope.draw = function() {

    if ($scope.shape === "circle") { 
       /* ... */ 
    } else {}


    // change color on mouseover
    d3.selectAll("circle,rect,polygon")
      .on("mouseover", function() {
        d3.select(this).style("fill", "#0f0");
      });
  }
```

While you are manipulating the DOM in D3-land, you should not rely on event-handlers defined in Angular's link function. In the directives I have written, I merely used `$watch` in the directives to trigger the `redraw` function when the data updated, just as you are doing with the `change` function.

---

**Alternate solution**

On the other hand, if you want to handle the events in the directive (e.g. if you do not have to pass `d3` the `$scope`), **and** if you are using *jQuery*, then [you can use the `.on` method on a parent with proper `selectors`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Note that `jQlite` (Angular's internal implementation of jQuery), [does not supposed `.on` with `selectors`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

In this case, the event handler will be called on the parent even if you change the DOM underneath. If you want access to the `data` associated with the node inside the event handler, you can use `var data = d3.select(this).data()`.

Comment: I tried that and it works well, but if I do that all my directives are going to be empty:
I currently have two nested controllers (data generation) and 5 or 6 directives (plot,thumbnail preview, brush, filters etc...) that use these controllers. All the data variables and event callbacks are in the controllers and the directives only have the event listeners. If I move the listeners to the controller, my directives seem pretty much empty and useless... Is it a problem?

Comment: @Titi No, there isn't a problem with that approach. Please see updated answer.